# Netsuite saved search formula to show inventory value on a specific date

Tags: date, search, formula, netsuite

I am running a saved search to show inventory items sold during a certain period. and i want to know the total value of an item at a specific date...

In the formula(currency) i use {item.totalvalue} but this only gives me the total value for the day the search is run.

Thanks in advance and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable maybe not in a single saved search. Basically you have to query all the transactions that affect inventory levels from the beginning of that item's life in Netsuite and total the adds and deletes. These depend on how your Netsuite account is configured. Also depending on setup you may be able to bypass using a list of transaction types by basing your search on transaction lines where the account type is inventory.

You can check your work by running the Inventory Valuation Detail report for the target date.

The simplest form is like:

Criteria:

| Filter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Voided | is false |
| Account : Type | is any of Other Current Asset, Other Asset |
| Item : Type | is Inventory Item |
| Posting | is true |
| Item | is targetItem |
| Date | onOrBefore targetDate |

Results:

| Field | Summary Type | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item | Group |  |
| Item : Average Cost | Minimum |  |
| Item : On Hand | Minimum |  |
| Date | Group |  |
| Type |  |  |
| Document Number |  |  |
| Account |  |  |
| Amount (Credit) | Sum |  |
| Amount (Debit) | Sum |  |
| Formula (Numeric) | Sum | nvl({debitamount},0)-nvl({creditamount},0) |
| Quantity | Sum |  |

Comment: Ok, can you ellaborate on how to query all the transactions as ytou mention?
Also, i have the feeling this should be also doable. considering the valuation detail reporte does exactkly that. evaluate the inventory valuation at a specific date.

Comment: Edited to show a working example.  There may be variations because of how your account is set up.